Заполнение документа в 1С
1С 8.3 Имеется документ с реквизитами, реквизиты не проверяются, все кроме статуса, но нужно чтобы если человек не заполнил статус, то всего лишь выводилось предупреждение, но документ проводился, а за место статуса указывался статус (По умолчанию), подскажите как это программно реализовать, пробовал такой код
&НаКлиенте
Процедура ПередЗаписью(Отказ, РежимЗаписи, РежимПроведения)
    Если Объект.Статус.Пустая() = Истина Тогда
        Объект.Статус="Черновик";
        Предупреждение("Выбрано значение по умолчанию"); 
    КонецЕсли;
КонецПроцедуры

Программа не выводит ошибок, но и при проведении с пустой строчкой статуса просто проводит документ

Реквизит "Статус" какого типа?

Как я понимаю реквизит Статус имеет строковый тип, поэтому можно воспользоваться методом ЗначениеЗаполнено
Описание:
Глобальный контекст.ЗначениеЗаполнено (Global context.ValueIsFilled)
Глобальный контекст (Global context)
ЗначениеЗаполнено (ValueIsFilled)
Синтаксис:
ЗначениеЗаполнено(<Значение>)
Параметры:
<Значение> (обязательный)
Тип: Произвольный.
Значение для проверки.
Возвращаемое значение:
Тип: Булево.
Для значений типа Булево всегда возвращается Истина.
Для значений типа Строка возвращается Истина, если в строке есть непробельные символы.
Для массивов и коллекций возвращается Истина, если в них есть хотя бы 1 элемент.
Для Неопределено и Null всегда возвращается Ложь.
Описание:
Функция проверяет, отличается ли переданное значение от значения по умолчанию того же типа.
Не работает с мутабельными значениями. При передаче мутабельного значения функция вызывает исключение.
Доступность:
Тонкий клиент, веб-клиент, мобильный клиент, сервер, толстый клиент, внешнее соединение, мобильное приложение(клиент), мобильное приложение(сервер).
Примечание:
Источники данных не проверяются, значение считается заполненным всегда.
 
&НаКлиенте
Процедура ПередЗаписью(Отказ, РежимЗаписи, РежимПроведения)
    Если Не ЗначениеЗаполнено(Объект.Статус) Тогда
        Объект.Статус="Черновик";
        Предупреждение("Выбрано значение по умолчанию"); 
    КонецЕсли;
КонецПроцедуры
 

пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
